# Link between Models in Django

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-forms

I am new to Django. I wanted to know how to link data of the foreign key. Here is the code.

```
 class CreateSchool(models.Model):

        schoolName = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=250)

    class SchoolDetails(models.Model):

        createSchool = models.OneToOneField(CreateSchool,to_field='schoolName')

        principalName = models.CharField(max_length=250)

        schoolAddress = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    class kidDetails(models.Model):

        schoolUID = models.ForeignKey(SchoolDetails,to_field='schoolUID')

        childName= models.CharField(max_length=245)

        childUID = models.CharField(max_length=245)
```

my question is when i enter the details of the kid, how to store the kids data with respect to schoolDetails and createschool model from the UI.

When i do it from admin panel, it dont allow me to save kids data unless i create a school and schooldetails.

For example, I need to store kid A in 1 school and i want to store kid 2 in 2 school. How to achieve this. I am completely beginner.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the example below:

```
class PaymentPlan():

  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  amount = models.FloatField(null=True)
  discount = models.FloatField(null=True)
  discount_amount = models.FloatField(null=True)
  no_of_users = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=100)
  no_of_brands = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=100)
  no_of_jobs = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=100)
  payment_data = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=100)
  plan_type = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=100)

class AccountSubscriptionDetail():
  plan = models.ForeignKey(PaymentPlan, related_name="plan_data")
  expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
  charge = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=100)
  billing_cycle = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=100)
  account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name="account_sub_data")
```

Here i have defined foreignkeys connect to other modal you can use in this way

Comment: Thankyou so much for replying.  when i send data to AccountSubscriptionDetail(), How to save data under the right Payment plan. I might be having 1,2,3,4 plans. How do i save under 2.

Comment: Just pass it to plan_id

please upvote the answer if you find some useful

Comment: Suppose you have added the plans their id will be "id"  and it will be "plan_id" for accountsubscriptiondetail means use id from plans table as a plan_id in accountsubscriptiondetail

Comment: I have taken your answer. Just let me know one more thing. How do i keep a track of all ID's.  should we send that from front end? I mean to say should i prepopulate the id somewhere and pass it. If not ID can i make the school name as primary and pass that?

Comment: Yes you have to pass a id from somewhere to add data relate to that id if you want to pass school name instead please make key on that basis instead of plan_id

please upvote

Comment: In my code above, in createschool model, school name is primary key,so there wont be any id, if i pass the school name, that should be good enough?

Comment: why not you use school_id instead

Comment: Ok. I 'll pass the school name and I 'll query with school name and get the id and pass. Is that right?

Comment: Yes you can do it.